# Is it possible to include the last entity of a related entity from the main entity with Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I know that Entity Framework Core allows to filter the related entities that I want to include, but in my case I want to include only the entity which is the max datetime of all the related entities.

I am trying something like this:

```
_context.Buyer
        .Include(x => x.Order.Max(y => y.PurchaseDate))
        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 1);
```

But `Max` is not accepted in the include.

Is there some way to include the last order of a buyer in only one query?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following query:

```cs
_context.Buyer
    .Include(x => x.Order.OrderByDescending(y => y.PurchaseDate).Take(1))
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 1);
```